# XAML parsing exception unless XBF is disabled

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

UWP project, C#. The main page XAML is quite involved and contains numerous custom classes, so I won't be pasting it here.

When I load the app, I get an exception: `XamlParseException`, the message is "XAML parsing failed." No InnerException, HRESULT is 0x802b000a.

HOWEVER, if I disable XAML compilation by inserting `<DisableXbfGeneration>true</DisableXbfGeneration>` into the project file, it loads and generally works.

How's that even possible? Either XAML is valid or it's not. Any hint on debugging this would be welcome.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose your issue if you cannot provide a [mcve].

Comment: Working on that... Commenting out fragments of the XAML renders the project uncompileable, so I have to go over and comment large chunks of C# too :(